# Rails hash to array to hash how to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller I have:

```
def index
    @title = 'asdsadas'
    @kategoris = Tag.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
    @kate = @kategoris.map(&:attributes).map{|d| d.map{|d| d.map{|d| d.dup.force_encoding("UTF-8") if d.respond_to?(:force_encoding) } } }
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @kate }
    end
end
```

The problem is it has become an array:

```
[[["cached_slug","vinna-biljetter"],["created_at",null],["h1","inn biljetter - Delta i tävl
```

It should be a hash:

```
[{"cached_slug":"vinna-biljetter","created_at":"2011-04-28T10:33:05Z","h1":"inn biljetter -
```

Comment: Try turning the array into a hash then pass the hash into json.      format.json { render :json => Hash[@kate] } I am not 100% sure if that would work but try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@kate = []
@kategoris.each do |kat|
  h = {}
  kat.attributes.each{|k,v| h[k] = v.respond_to?(:force_encoding) ? v.dup.force_encoding("UTF-8") : v }
  @kate << h
end
```

OR

```
 @kate = @kategoris.map{|k| k.attributes.inject({}){|h,(k,v)| h[k] = v.respond_to?(:force_encoding) ? v.dup.force_encoding("UTF-8") : v;h}}
```

`@kate` is now an array of hashes.

Comment: I get this error in view: undefined method `attributes' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x745cd40>

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize there were multiple @kategoris. Try the editted code.

Comment: It removes the attributes, created_at and ID which is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@kate = @kategoris.map |k|
 Hash[
   k.attributes.select{|k, v| v.respond_to?(:force_encoding)}.
     map{|k, v| [k, v.force_encoding("UTF-8")]}
 ]
end
```

**PS:**

The solution above selects only the values that support `force_encoding`. If you want to include other values:

```
@kate = @kategoris.map |k|
 Hash[
   k.attributes.map{|k, v| 
     [k, (v.respond_to?(:force_encoding) ? v.force_encoding("UTF-8") : v)]
   }
 ]
end
```

Comment: I get a syntax error with the first and last code: tags_controller.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected '|'
 @ kate = @ kategoris.map begin |k|

Comment: I used .map{ |k| insted and } instead of end

Answer (score 0):

There's always the Hash[*] trick:

```
Hash[*[['foo',1],['bar',2]].flatten]
=> {"foo"=>1, "bar"=>2}
```

Comment: Tried it, returned only 1 hash.

Comment: Hash[[['foo',1],['bar',2]]]
#=> {"foo"=>1, "bar"=>2}

you can actually do this and not have to flatten.

Answer (score 0):

This may not completely answer the question, still 
If you just want to convert a Hash to Array, just call to_a on the hash.

```
h = { "c" => 300, "a" => 100, "d" => 400, "c" => 300  }
h.to_a   #=> [["c", 300], ["a", 100], ["d", 400]]
```

Reference:
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-to_a